# C# Interactive: Hosting process exited with exit code -1073741819

Tags: c#, c#-interactive

I started my Visual Studio 2017, and opened C# Interactive.
When I experimented with the following code, I get a rather special error message:

```
> System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(((object)typeof(object)).GetType())
Hosting process exited with exit code -1073741819.
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
>
```

So I tried to surround it with try/catch, and it seemed to work (not exiting the process):

```
> try { System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(((object)typeof(object)).GetType()); } catch (Exception ex) { }
>
```

Then I tried to get the type of Exception:

```
> try { System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(((object)typeof(object)).GetType()); } catch (Exception ex) { WriteLine(ex.GetType()); }
>
```

No output? Weird... I tried outputting the "uninitialized object", and it started exiting the process again...

```
> try { WriteLine(System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(((object)typeof(object)).GetType())); } catch (Exception ex) { WriteLine(ex.GetType()); }
Hosting process exited with exit code -1073741819.
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
>
```

Catching everything did not work either:

```
> try { WriteLine(System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(((object)typeof(object)).GetType())); } catch { }
Hosting process exited with exit code -1073741819.
Loading context from 'CSharpInteractive.rsp'.
>
```

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Comment: What is `((object)typeof(object)).GetType()` supposed to do here? The whole line is giving an uncatchable exception.

Comment: @DavidG It is just me experimenting with C#, but I would like to learn something from this. You said it is giving an uncatchable exception, but the last code I provided does have a catch clause that catches everything - not just exceptions. I am confused.

Comment: I just ran the code in LinqPad and it said the exception was un-catchable.

Comment: I just ran the code in C# Pad (http://csharppad.com/) and it said an internal server error has occurred.